# Android development, Closing fragment using toggle button

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, togglebutton

I think the issue is probably simple, but being pretty new to Java and to Android dev, I'm not really sure. What I'm trying to do is close a fragment that's been toggled on using a ToggleButton, but I can't find a way to then hide or close it. Any help would be appreciated.

Below is the code for the OnCheckChanged() listener.

```
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

    MyFragment frag = new MyFragment();
    FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();

    transaction.add(R.id.main_activity, frag, "Fragment1");

    if(isChecked)
    {
        transaction.show(frag);
    }
    else
    {
        transaction.hide(frag);
        //transaction.remove(frag);
    }

    transaction.commit();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time you hit onCheckedChanged, you are adding a **NEW** fragment and then either hiding or showing it.  All other fragments you have previously created are still attached laid one on top of the other.

You should get the current fragment that is attached to the layout if there is one.  If there isn't one already, create it and add it to the container.

For example, this should point you in the right direction.

```
private void HideFragment(){

    // Get the fragment that is attached to the layout
    Fragment frag=getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.centerFrame);

    if (frag==null){
        // The fragment does not exist yet so create one and add it
        frag=new MyFragment();
        getFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.centerFrame,frag)
                .commit();
    }

    //Hide the fragment
    getFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .hide(frag)
            .commit();


}
```

**Update:**
It is a little ambiguous what you are actually trying to achieve. You keep saying "close" the fragment but your code suggests you just want to toggle its visibility on and off.

If you actually want to completely remove the fragment then you should use the `Remove` method of the `FragmentTransaction`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. A question on the code you posted... findFragmentById(R.id.centerFrame); In this bit of code, the "R.id.centerFrame" is the fragment we are trying to close?

Comment: If the above is the case, then I'm a little confused on how the frame is suppose to be referenced in findFragmentById(). In the code you posted the argument provided is R.id.centerFrame, but in my code I'm not really sure what the argument would be.

Comment: centreFrame is just the FrameLayout I am using to host the Fragment in my example. You would use whatever container is in your layout (looking at your code, most likely main_activity).

Comment: I didn't use `main_activity` because it seems a very strange name for a fragment host container and I have not seen your layout so did not want to make assumptions. The name `main_activity` suggests it is an activity layout. My code is an example only and not intended to be used "as is"

Comment: Yeah, I understand that it's not suppose to be used "as is". transaction.add(R.id.main_activity, frag, "Fragment1"); There's a snippet of my code. I'm assuming that given this, that the right argument would in fact be R.id.main_activity, but when I change it to that it gives me an "incompatible types" error. BTW, thanks again for your help.

Comment: Like I said,  I haven't seen your layout so cannot guess what your container name is.

Comment: I was able to get it to work by using: findFragmentByTag("Fragment"). Thank you for the help again. In reference to your update, simply hiding the fragment is fine for my purposes. Sorry for the ambiguity.

Comment: I also had to do a cast to get rid of the "incompatible types" error: FragmentClass frag= (FragmentClass) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("Fragment1");